# Scope hiding in C

Tags: c, scope

Does C have scope hiding?

For example, if I have a global variable:

```
int x = 3;
```

can I 'declare' inside a function or main 'another' int x?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's how C works. For example:

```
int x;

void my_function(int x){ // this is another x, not the same one
}

void my_function2(){
  int x; //this is also another x
  {
    int x; // this is yet another x
  }
}
int main(){
  char x[5]; // another x, with a different type
}
```

Comment: What if in the main it was not int as well (different type), for example char array[5] x ?

Comment: in such cases, the type doesn't matter. if you declare `x` as an `int` and then you shadow that declaration by saying that you have a new `x` of type `char[5]`, you will only see the latter `char x[5]`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes but some compilers complain or can be told to complain. For `gcc`, use `-Wshadow`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Scope Hiding exists in C.
A variable in local scope will hide the same named variable in global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is very much possible. Please go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824301/terminology-definition-scope-in-c-application/8824889#8824889) post for a detailed explanation on various scope in `C`