# Re-declaring variable inside for loop in C

Tags: c, gcc, declaration

I have compiled following program using  `gcc prog.c -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu11 -pedantic` command on [GCC](https://wandbox.org/permlink/V9LPlXWlLVKdR3Q7) compiler. I wondered, it is working fine without any warnings or errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i == 0;  i++) 
    {        
        printf("%d\n", i);
        long int i = 1; // Why doesn't redeclaration error?
        printf("%ld\n", i);
    }
}
```

Why compiler doesn't generate redeclaration variable `i` error?

Comment: Are you also not getting a warning that `int main` is not returning a value?

Comment: @MFisherKDX Cppreference says: "The body of the main function does not need to contain the return statement: if control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing return 0;"

Comment: Per 5.1.2.2.3 of n1570 (C11 draft): "reaching the } that terminates the main function returns a value of 0" (so long as the return type is compatible with `int`.)

Comment: In C99 and later, for (misguided?) conformity with C++98, you're allowed to omit the `return 0;` at the end of `main()` (but only of `main()` — no other function gets the special treatment) and it is equivalent to `return 0;` at the end.  Personally, I don't think it was a good decision and I have a policy of not taking advantage of the permission.  I can't stop others from doing it, though — I can only recommend that they don't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scope hiding in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928521/scope-hiding-in-c)

Comment: @OmG, no not at all a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @OmG No, it's not duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C language, the scope of `statement` is nested within the scope of for loop `init-statement`.

According to [Cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) :

> While in C++, the scope of the init-statement and the scope of
>   statement are one and the same, **in C the scope of `statement` is nested
>   within the scope of `init-statement`**.

According to [stmt](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/open/n2356/stmt.html):

> The for statement
>
> ```
> for ( for-init-statement conditionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> {
>     for-init-statement
>     while ( condition ) {
>             statement
>             expression ;
>       }
> }
> ```
>
> except  that  names declared in the for-init-statement are in the same   declarative-region as those declared in the condition,
>   and except that   a  continue in statement (not enclosed in another
>   iteration statement)   will execute expression before re-evaluating
>   condition.

Comment: you should stop referring to c**pp**reference when answering your language-lawyer C questions. It is known to contain errors even for C++.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, agreed that this is not always the best choice as a source. But here it is right and makes an important point, namely that C and C++ have different rules for that. There has even been a defect report on this for C (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2148.htm#dr_466), and it turned out that this difference was unintentional, but that it was too late to change that.

Comment: @JensGustedt the actual standards are much better references. And that DR

Comment: @AnttiHaapala cppreference also has a C reference section, the corresponding page is [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/for). (But I agree the standard is more authoritative of course).

Answer (score 6):

From standard §6.8.5.5 ([N1570](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.5))

> An iteration statement is a block whose scope is a strict subset of
>   the scope of its enclosing block. **The loop body is also a block whose
>   scope is a strict subset of the scope of the iteration statement.**

<sup>*Emphasis added*</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You have to set -Wshadow to get warnings on shadowed variables. Variable shadowing is allowed in C.

But this is an edge case. A var declared in the head of a `for` construction is not outside the brackets, because it has no scope after the construction.

This is *not* equivalent:

```
int i;
for( i = 0; …)
{ … }
// is is still in scope but wouldn't if declared in the head of for
```

But, it is not inside the brackets, too.

```
for( i = 0; …)
{ 
  int i; // this would be strange, because i is used before it is declared.
  … 
}
```

The best approximative replacement of the code is this:

```
{
  int i;
  for( i = 0; …)
  {
  … 
  }
}  // i loses scope
```

So it is no redeclaration, but a shadowing declaration inside the loop's body.

Comment: I don't think that this is what the question is about, but why the `for` declaration and the one inside the `{}` aren't in the same declaration scope.

Comment: An identifier declare in tne `for` is outside the brackets used in the body. Its scope includes the expressions in the `for`. The scope of an identifier inside the brackets does not.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Indeed. Why do you comment so?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: Your answer says “A var declared in the head of a `for` construction is not outside the brackets, because it has no scope after the construction.” That is false. An identifier declared in the head of a `for` has scope outside the brackets. The part inside the `for` header is outside the brackets.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Reading the whole post, it should be quite clear to everybody (at last nearly everybody), that this means "simply outside the brackets as a declaration in front of for".

Comment: The sentence is false. The answer could be written better.

Comment: @EricPostpischil No, picking up a single sentence from a text is wrong.

Comment: A purpose of comments is point out things in the answer that could be improved.

Answer (score 0):

> `Why compiler doesn't generate redeclaration variable i error?`

From [C Standards#6.2.1p4 Scopes of identifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.1p4)

> Every other identifier has scope determined by the placement of its declaration (in a declarator or type specifier). If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier appears outside of any block or list of parameters, the identifier has file scope, which terminates at the end of the translation unit. If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier appears inside a block or within the list of parameter declarations in a function definition, the identifier has block scope, which terminates at the end of the associated block. If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier appears within the list of parameter declarations in a function prototype (not part of a function definition), the identifier has function prototype scope, which terminates at the end of the function declarator. If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the scope of one entity (the inner scope) will end strictly before the scope of the other entity (the outer scope). **Within the inner scope, the identifier designates the entity declared in the inner scope; the entity declared in the outer scope is hidden (and not visible) within the inner scope.**

From [C standards#6.8.5p5 Iteration statements](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.5p5)

> An iteration statement is a block whose scope is a strict subset of the scope of its enclosing block. The loop body is also a block whose scope is a strict subset of the scope of the iteration statement.

So, in this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i == 0;  i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", i);
    long int i = 1; // Why doesn't redeclaration error?
    printf("%ld\n", i);
}
```

the scope of identifier with name `i` is overlapping and in this name space, the `i` declared in `for (int i = 0; i == 0;  i++)` has **outer scope** and the one declared within loop body `long int i = 1;` has **inner scope**.

Within the loop body, after this statement:

```
long int i = 1;
```

the `i` declared in the outer scope is **not visible** and `printf()` printing the value of `i` visible in the inner scope which is `1`.

This behavior is also known as **Variable Shadowing** which occurs when a variable declared within a certain scope has the same name as a variable declared in an outer scope.

C language allows variable shadowing and that's why **the compiler does not throw any error for this**. However, in `gcc` compiler, if you use `-Wshadow` option you will get a warning message - `declaration shadows a local variable`.

Answer (score 0):

For further verification i checked this code in visual studio 2008 for the prog.c file. I found that the compiler does give error in the line for (int i = 0; i == 0;  i++) . The compiler expects declaration of i to be in the beginning of the program itself. This behavior is correct for a C file. If the declaration is moved to the beginning of the program then there are no errors as expected. All scope related issues are solved.

If i try this code as prog.cpp file, then the compiler does give an error for redeclaration. This is also an expected behavior.

So i conclude this has to do with the gcc compiler, does any flag/parameters that is used for compiling/building the exe results in this behavior for the gcc compiler.

Can rsp post the make file details for further verification?