# What does {} mean in these c++ functions?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve some problems in c++ but I have never seen this expression before. Since I don't know what the expression is called, I can't google it.

```
int main() {
   int something=1;

   {
     assert(something);
   }

   // What is the purpose of these braces?
   // and what is it called?
   {
     assert(something != NULL);
   }

   return;
}
```

Comment: They are creating additional local scope blocks. Presumably `assert()` is a precompiler macro that internally declares some variables that should go out of scope when `assert()` exits, but doesn't itself declare its own scope blocks

Comment: Why is this question too broad? Its a very specific question with a narrow context.

Comment: Whatever, I got my answer. I don't care about my SO reputation. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @Dr.Knowitall I'd suppose that closing was suggested because questions on basic language constructs are usually commented with "get a good C++ book" and closed. What is "basic" and what isn't is not entirely clear to me, though.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704083/unnecessary-curly-braces-in-c)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This use of curly brackets creates a new [block scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope).

Each time you write `if (...) { ... }` or `while (...) { ... }`, the `{ ... }` part is a new scope. All objects with automatic storage duration created inside (which are usual variables, but not objects allocated dynamically, e.g. via `new`) will be destroyed upon reaching the end of the scope. A scope without any `if`, `while` etc. is useful if you need to constrain the lifetime of something. For example:

```
{
    std::vector<float> some_data = get_the_data();
    send_somewhere(some_data);
    send_somewhere_else(some_data);
}
```

Here, after reaching `}`, the `some_data` object will be destroyed, the memory it allocated will be freed, and you ***cannot*** forget to delete it, since it's deletion is guaranteed by the language itself.

Another common example is mutex locking:

```
// some preparation code
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock { my_lovely_mutex };
    some_shared_resource.modify();
}
// something that does not need the mutex to be locked
```

Here, the `lock_guard` locks the mutex on creation, and unlocks on destruction, even if `modify()` throws an exception. Again, you ***cannot*** forget to unlock the mutex (and forgetting this is a very dangerous thing to do).

---

That being said, I don't know the reason to put an `assert` into a separate scope - a proper `assert`, be it a function or a macro, is usually a self-contained statement and does not need this hackery.

As pointed by Remy Lebeau, probably the assert macro that the author used didn't possess the aforementioned properties, and created variables inside or did something else that pollutes the scope it is called from, thus prohibiting from using it twice. For example, if it were declared (hypothetically) as

```
#define assert(x) bool b = (x); _internal_assert(b);
```

Then doing

```
assert(x);
assert(y);
```

would trigger a compilation error, because this will expand into

```
bool b = (x); _internal_assert(b);
bool b = (y); _internal_assert(b);
```

where the variable `b` is declared twice.

Hiding such an `assert` in it's own scope fixes this, because variables declared in different scopes do not disturb each other:

```
{
    bool b = (x); _internal_assert(b);
}
// ...
{
    bool b = (y); _internal_assert(b);
}
```

Comment: "*probably the assert macro that the author used didn't possess the aforementioned properties*" - And the fix for such a "broken" macro would be something like this: `#define assert(x) do { bool b = (x); _internal_assert(b); } while(false);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau True! This is the `assert` I'm most familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

- { Denotes the start of a block
- } Denotes the end of a block

Blocks effect scope.
In the case you've presented, they serve no purpose other than to meet the style of the author.